# Prevent stretching of corners on UIView Layer after transform.scale.y animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, swift3, calayer

My UIView subclass layoutSubviews() function contains the following:

```
    var path = UIBezierPath()
    path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners:    [UIRectCorner.allCorners], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))

    self.fillLayer.path = path.cgPath
    self.maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
```

Im doing a simple scaling animation on my UIView layer: to keep it in position and extend its height by a factor of 2.

All of that works with these CABasicAnimations:

```
    let scale:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath:"transform.scale.y");
    scale.fromValue = 1.0;
    scale.toValue = 2.0;
    scale.duration = 10.0;
    scale.isRemovedOnCompletion = false;
    scale.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    let position:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath:"position.y");
    position.byValue = layer.frame.height/2;
    position.duration = 10.0;
    position.isRemovedOnCompletion = false;
    position.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    let cornerRadius:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath:"cornerRadius");
    cornerRadius.byValue = 0;
    cornerRadius.duration = 10.0;
    cornerRadius.isRemovedOnCompletion = false;
    cornerRadius.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    layer.add(position, forKey: "basic1");
    layer.add(scale, forKey: "basic2");
    layer.add(cornerRadius, forKey: "cornerRadius");
```

But the problem is after the animation is finished my rounded corners look stretched out and I'm not sure how to prevent this from happening, unless I create 3 views, a top, bottom and middle, and only stretch the middle.

Here's the problem in a picture -- please see left green uiview for post-animation corners I want, and right green uiview for the post-animaton corners I am currently getting
[image]

Thanks!!!

Comment: do you really need `transform.scale.y`? cant you just animate the view's height getting larger? transforming the scale afaik will just stretch whatever is rendered to the layer (including rounded corners), but if you change the height instead, it will be rendered properly for that height.

Comment: animating the maskLayer's frame with CABasicAnimation with the keyPath "path" seems to work, thank you for your suggestion.